LWC not displaying related records
I have an LWC component, so on search I am fetching and showing data table from user object and related object, user object fields are showing but having issue with related record data, below is the query which I am having
String query = 'SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name, Email, ' +
                   '(SELECT MrTitle__c, MsTitle__c ' +
                   ' FROM LCBProfiles__r) ' +
                   'FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND ProfileId IN :profileId';

below is what I have in my lwc
handleSearch() {
const firstNameValid = this.firstName.length >= 3;
const lastNameValid = this.lastName.length >= 3;
const emailValid = this.email.length >= 3;

if (!firstNameValid && !lastNameValid && !emailValid) {
    this.errorMessage = 'Please enter at least 3 characters in any of the fields to perform a search.';
    return;
}

this.errorMessage = ''; // Clear error message before search

searchUsers({ firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, email: this.email })
.then(result => {
    if (result.length === 0) {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'No Records Found',
                message: 'No users match the search criteria.',
                variant: 'warning',
            }),
        );
    } else {
        // If users are found, update the data table with the results
        this.userRecords = result.map(user => {
            // Extract the related fields (assuming one related record per user)
            const relatedRecords = LCBProfiles__r || [];
            const relatedRecord = relatedRecords.length > 0 ? relatedRecords[0] : {};
            
            return {
                ...user,
                Title1: relatedRecord.MrTitle__c || '',
                Title2: relatedRecord.MsTitle__c || ''
            };
        });
        this.currentPage = 1; // Reset to first page
        this.updatePagination(); // Update pagination after search
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error',
            message: 'An error occurred while searching for users.',
            variant: 'error',
        }),
    );
    console.error('Error searching users:', error);
});}

can anyone help me out in this issue here

Wouldn't const relatedRecords = LCBProfiles__r || []; need to be const relatedRecords = user.LCBProfiles__r || [];

I think the way you're getting your related records is missing the references to the user record.
ie. change const relatedRecords = LCBProfiles__r || [];
to const relatedRecords = user.LCBProfiles__r || [];

I tried the same but still two fields are coming as balank even though I have related record
